# PowerShell GWMI win32_operatingsystem trim output

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting

When you use

```
(GWMI -ComputerName $server -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction Stop).Caption
```

to get captions like

```
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Standard x64 Edition
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
```

What's an easy way to remove `"Microsoft Windows"` and `"Microsoft(R) Windows"` from the results?

I have come up with:

```
(GWMI Win32_OperatingSystem -Comp $server).Caption -Replace "^Microsoft Windows "
```

Which turns `"Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Datacenter"` into `"Server 2012 Datacenter"`, but the old machines on [Windows Server 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) and [Windows Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) don't match the replace regex.

Answer (score 4):

Here is mine:

```
gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem | % Caption
```

Output:

```
Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
```

And what you want:

```
gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem | % Caption | % split ' ' 3 | select -last 1
```

Output:

```
7 Ultimate
```

Comment: Now that looked too easy!  Thank you!  -edit, I can't seem to post the revised code I've got but here's the one liner: `$result.OS = (GWMI -ComputerName $server -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction Stop).Caption | % split | select -Skip 2 | & {"$input" }`

Answer (score 3):

I found all the OSes in my environment as a test. I am not going to worry about the [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) for this answer as that is not the focus of the question.

Using the following [here-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) which contained all my examples for testing,

```
$OSes = @"
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
Microsoft Windows Storage Server 2008 R2 Standard
Microsoft Windows XP Professional
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Standard Edition
Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008 Standard
"@.Split("`r`n")
```

I run a regex that finds Microsoft Windows with optional (R) and ® (<-- copyright symbol):

```
$OSes -replace "Microsoft(\(R\)|®)?\sWindows(\(R\))?\s"
```

More verbose information on the regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/dT0rV9/1).

Which nets the output

```
7 Professional
8.1 Pro
Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
Server 2008 R2 Standard
Storage Server 2008 R2 Standard
XP Professional
Server 2003, Standard Edition
Server® 2008 Standard
```

Comment: Thank you also, here is it in action: `$result.OS = (GWMI -ComputerName $server -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction Stop).Caption -replace "Microsoft(\(R\)|®)?\sWindows(\(R\))?\s"`

Answer (score 1):

I would carry on with the regex approach and go with 'Microsoft {optionally followed by (R)}' like this example:

```
$s = @(   'Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Standard x64 Edition'
        , 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard'
        , 'Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Datacenter'
    )

write "`n`n"

$s | % { $_ -replace "Microsoft(\(R\)|) Windows(\(R\)|) " }
```

Comment: @Matt : Aye! (I probably only saw it while you were looking at it because your edit bumped it to the top of the front page, though).